# Make smooth angle line between two borders

Tags: css

I obtain jagged (pixeled) line when I am trying to create angle between two borders.

Please, consider the following code:

```
  <div id="example"></div>

   #example:before{
    content: "";
    position: relative;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -40px;
    border-top: 20px solid black;
    border-left: 470px solid red;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pan1cmode/bQYU7/2/

Any suggestions on how make it smooth?

Comment: Your fiddle is blank.

Comment: I made one here: http://jsfiddle.net/bQYU7/1/

Comment: I doubt that css supports antialising, I would be very pleased to get corrected on this but I doubt it.

Comment: Don't know if you like it or not, but this is what I got working with some fiddling: http://jsfiddle.net/bQYU7/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, what you want is called anti-aliasing, as Layne commented.

One way to get that, somehow, is using gradients.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bQYU7/7/)

```
#Ex2 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 40px;
    width: 470px;
    top: 80px;
    background: linear-gradient(3deg, red 39px, black 42px);
}
```

You can adjust the degree of smoothing by the difference between the red and the black stop. (in this case, between 39 and 42 px )

Answer (score 0):

actually it is stretching because `border-left` value is value is very higher if you use equal values than you will solve this problem

http://jsfiddle.net/bQYU7/3/

Comment: Here is the thing... I need that certain angle to cut my another div. But now I think I can solve my problem using svg.